# can i pass specific index of string in Integer.parseInt( string_array [0])

Tags: java, string, algorithm, wrapper

I was trying to convert specific index of `String[]` array into `int`

```
String retdates[]=adates.split(" ");
int ad =Integer.ParseInt(retdates[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert string to int then `int ad =Integer.parseInt(//your string value);`

That means you just need to pass your string parameter in the `parseInt` method. And `parseInt` is a method of Integer class so it will be `parseInt()` not `ParseInt()`

See the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int- for more information..

Comment: thanks .. that helped